# Adding packages in the Azure online code editor

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-language-understanding

I want to use the [restsharp package](http://restsharp.org/) in my Luis Web App Bot. But when I add the

```
using RestSharp;
```

statement to

> BasicLuisDialog.cs

and build the assembly via build.cmd in the console, I get

> The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found

How can I add an assembly reference in the Azure online code editor?

Comment: Have you installed the NuGet package via the NuGet package manager or by right clicking on the solution in Solution Explorer and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution"? Please check https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

Comment: I know how to do that locally. The problem occured in the Azure online code editor - please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line: `<package id="RestSharp" version="106.3.1" targetFramework="net46" />` to your packages.config file, then run build from the console again.

Comment: I have switched to the continuos integration workflow to avoid such workarounds